# How to search a row in datatable using c#.net

Tags: c#, select, datatable, ienumerable

I have a datatable in c#.net with below columns So first I fill this data table and second I try to get data from it by searching.

```
 void CalculateEzafkari2()
        {
            calEzaf = new DataTable();
            calEzaf.Columns.Add("IDp");
            calEzaf.Columns.Add("duration");
            calEzaf.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
            calEzaf.Clear();
            foreach (var item in EzafArray)
            {
                if (item.Value.Count()%2==0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Value.Count(); i = i + 2)
                    {
                        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(item.Value[i]);
                        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(item.Value[i + 1]);
                        TimeSpan tp = dt2 - dt1;
                        calEzaf.Rows.Add(item.Key, tp.ToString(), dt1);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Value.Count()-1; i = i + 2)
                    {
                        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(item.Value[i]);
                        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(item.Value[i + 1]);
                        TimeSpan tp = dt2 - dt1;
                        calEzaf.Rows.Add(item.Key, tp.ToString(), dt1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

so I use below code to extract data from it by I can not get data .this function does not return data.

```
public string ReadEzafKariFromDataTable(string IDp, DateTime dt)
        {
            string[] d = dt.ToString().Split(' ');

            IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows =
                calEzaf.AsEnumerable().Where(row => (row.Field<DateTime>("date").Equals(d[0])) && row.Field<int>("IDp")==(int.Parse(IDper)));
            foreach (DataRow row in selectedRows)
            {
                return row["duration"].ToString();
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: What you are expected this line `row.Field<DateTime>("date").Equals(d[0])` to do

Comment: I want to search By date and ID So I splited datetime by ('  ') to use first section of datetime like this '2017-02-10 12:24:23' I want to use only '2017-02-10' for search

Comment: you are inserting strings but expecting strongly typed data back? that is not going to happen

Comment: what shall I do????????????

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code:

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> selectedRows = calEzaf.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<DateTime>("date").Date == dt.Date && row.Field<int>("IDp") == int.Parse(IDper));
```

Comment: dear un-lucky : I used Ur Code But I encountred an errro "specified cast is not valid"

Comment: Make sure that the column `date` is of type DateTime

Comment: I defined it as a datetime .  calEzaf.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));

Comment: how about the column `IDp` is that of type integer?

Comment: It,s Working mate. Column names and type should be proper which we need to check from the Datatable data 'columns' property.ty